# JS If statement with dates

Tags: javascript

I want to add to my e-commerce website this: "Want it by Monday, Sept. 9? Order within 2 hrs 24 mins" by adding X days (estimated shipping days) to the current date. For this, I have the following code that I looked up on the web:

```
<div style="text-align: center;font-weight: 400; font-size: 19px; color: #002f40;" id="clockbox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var tmonth = ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "June", "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."];

function GetClock() {
    var n = 8; // Shipping time
    var today = new Date();
    var d = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + n)
    var nday = d.getDay(),
        nmonth = d.getMonth(),
        ndate = d.getDate();

    var clocktext = "<strong>Want it by <span style='color: #af3831;'>" + tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + [ndate] + " </span>?</strong>";
    document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = clocktext;
}

GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
```

However, no deliveries are made on Sundays and I want to exclude this day and make it next day instead. I tried to add this piece of code here:

```
var sunday = tday[nday];
document.getElementById('sundaytext').innerHTML = sunday;

if (sundaytext = "Sunday") {

    var clocktext = "<strong>Want it by <span style='color: #af3831;'> Monday, " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + [ndate+1] + " </span>?</strong>";
    } else

    var clocktext = "<strong>Want it by <span style='color: #af3831;'>" + tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + [ndate] + " </span>?</strong>";
    document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = clocktext;
```

It didn't work and as you can see this approach is not the brightest thing but my knowledge in JS is pretty limited and, therefore, I've joined this forum to ask for your help. Any comment is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer but could maybe help. If you struggeling with date calculation take a look at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: `if (sundaytext = "Sunday") ...` you're assigning "Sunday" to the variable, not checking to see if they are equal

Comment: @slebetman hmm thought that it would compare the variable. Will read about the if statements then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything fine except the variable name... it should be `if (sunday == "Sunday")` (or you can use `if(tday[nday]=="Sunday")` ) but you used `if (sundaytext = "Sunday")`.. there is no such a variable named 'sundaytext' in your code..

```
var sunday = tday[nday];
document.getElementById('sundaytext').innerHTML = sunday;

if (sunday == "Sunday") {
   var clocktext = "<strong>Want it by <span style='color: #af3831;'>Monday, " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + [ndate+1] + " </span>?</strong>";
} 
else{
  var clocktext = "<strong>Want it by <span style='color: #af3831;'>" + tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + [ndate] + " </span>?</strong>";    
}
document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = clocktext;
```

Answer (score 0):

should be :

```
if (sundaytext == "Sunday") {...}
```

Comment: I tried that one, but it is not working, it's like it doesn't make a difference.